# Set window size for standalone application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to set the default window size for a flex application that runs with a standalone player.
I set width and height to 100% to be able to get the ResizeEvent and being able to adjust the layout if the user changes the window size. But I'd like to also define a default size.

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways to set the default size of a swf:

1) add a compiler argument:

```
-default-size=800,600
```

2) use metadata in your flex main mxml or class

mxml:

```
<mx:Metadata>
     [SWF(width='800', height='600')]
</mx:Metadata>
```

class:

```
[SWF(width='800', height='600')]
public class Main extends Application {}
```

This will tell the compiler what values to put in the header tag of the swf.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:
setting the application to a fixed size on startup, and adjusting it when the stage (here: the window) is resized

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            width="900" height="600"
            applicationComplete="appComplete();">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        private function appComplete():void {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResize);
        }

        private function onStageResize(e:Event):void
        {
            this.width  = this.stage.stageWidth;
            this.height = this.stage.stageHeight;
            validateNow();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can. You can do it with air though. Why would you want a standalone flex app that isn't air?  The setting is the air xml file

Comment: I'd like a standalone app that isn't air because it does not need installing and can be run right away.